# SSRS 2016 visibility toggle not appearing

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with a hidden group. This group can be expanded with a toggle on  a text box within the parent group.

[image: From Visual Studio]

In SSRS2012, this toggle happily appears in the red circle.

However, in SSRS 2016, this is not appearing when viewed via the web portal. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @WEI_DBA Tried IE (8, 9, 10 and Edge compat modes), and firefox. This will ultimately have to work in ie.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm surprised you haven't tried IE 11.

Comment: @WEI_DBA It's not a browser issue. The **only** change is from SSRS2012 to SSRS2016

Comment: Understood. Are you using VS or Report Builder to edit the reports?

Comment: Created in VS, edited with report builder to see if the issue appears in there (it doesn't)